# Specifying input duration of .aac with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I had an error with an mp4 recording, and after recovering the video and audio streams I've still got an issue. The aac audio file is 160kb/s CBR. However, ffmpeg returns this when trying to work with it;

```
[aac @ 000001187e6944c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, aac, from 'result.aac':
  Duration: 00:38:41.01, bitrate: 174 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 174 kb/s
```

That duration and bitrate is totally wrong. It should be ~42 minutes long, and it definitely has a bitrate of 160 kb/s.

This results in the audio being very inconsistently timed, as well as having all sorts of other issues. It's very weird.

Is there any way I can specify that the input is 160 cbr to try and wrangle it back into a usable file?

Comment: How was the recording made?

Comment: With OBS. It was a stream recording that failed due to a full hard drive. I used recover_mp4 with a recording made with the same settings earlier in the same day to recover the audio and video tracks. The video track is perfect, it's just the audio track that has weird issues.

Comment: If OBS skips encoding audio packets during silence, then the original timing will have to be manually set in a video editor.

Comment: Sometimes reconverting with ffmpeg will corrects the details of the content

Comment: Is there any way to retime the audio broadly using ffmpeg without re-encoding the stream entirely? I don't know how to use stream mapping but I feel like that's the sort of thing I need.

Converting with ffmpeg didn't solve any issues, unfortunately